# Linear fitting of data with errors on y-axis in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataset with the cumulative ice mass change of the Greenland Ice Sheet (mc) with units Gt (Gigatonnes) and its uncertainty/error estimate (mc_error) over time (yr).

```
yr=[2003.038356 2003.117808 2003.208219 2003.287671 2003.358904 2003.539726 2003.619178 2003.709589 2003.789041 2003.879452 2003.958904 2004.019126 2004.128415 2004.20765  2004.289617 2004.379781 2004.459016 2004.538251 2004.628415 2004.70765  2004.789617 2004.879781 2004.959016];
mc=[94.91467285 -106.5794067    -39.28155518    -0.194824219    -4.950927734    -193.9120483    -397.7717896    -389.0446777    -302.5618896    -271.7980347    -341.026062 -325.5195313    -319.352417 -287.8536377    -210.249939 -255.0377808    -234.324707 -405.8927002    -533.7174072    -574.6280518    -641.2060547    -519.1424561    -509.010376];
mc_error=[281.3519897   178.404007  159.776001  135.2619934 186.845993  115.685997  127.3939972 122.6439972 101.6019974 111.5830002 110.0019989 243.348999  123.1790009 93.52189636 107.526001  162.6710052 194.0769958 233.6569977 876.4349976 418.4100037 698.5339966 162.121994  129.7559967];
```

I found a paper which used a linear regression to find the slope and its uncertainty (in Gt yr-1). The paper states that "the dashed blue lines represent the 2σ error envelope of this fit calculated using full covariance information estimated from the data themselves. This result gives a comprehensive measure of the variance of each coefficient and their dependencies, which we extend to the uncertainty of their sum by linear error propagation."

[image]

When I apply a linear regression to my data, I get a slope (or mean mass change) of -276.11 Gt yr-1. But I am wondering how to determine the uncertainty/error from these data as done in this paper (-276.11 +/- what?). Can someone help me to code this in Python? I have found the following code and applied it to my data but I don't know if it is correct:

```
xdata=np.array([2003.038356,2003.117808, 2003.208219, 2003.287671 ,2003.358904 ,2003.539726, 2003.619178 ,2003.709589 ,2003.789041 ,2003.879452 ,2003.958904 ,2004.019126, 2004.128415 ,2004.20765,2004.289617,2004.379781,2004.459016,2004.538251,2004.628415,2004.70765,2004.789617,2004.879781,2004.959016])
ydata=np.array([94.91467285, -106.5794067  ,  -39.28155518  ,  -0.194824219 ,   -4.950927734  ,  -193.9120483  ,  -397.7717896  ,  -389.0446777  ,  -302.5618896   , -271.7980347  ,  -341.026062, -325.5195313,    -319.352417, -287.8536377  ,  -210.249939, -255.0377808 ,   -234.324707, -405.8927002   , -533.7174072  ,  -574.6280518  ,  -641.2060547   , -519.1424561 ,   -509.010376])
d_y=np.array([281.3519897  , 178.404007  ,159.776001 , 135.2619934, 186.845993 , 115.685997 , 127.3939972 ,122.6439972 ,101.6019974 ,111.5830002, 110.0019989, 243.348999 , 123.1790009, 93.52189636 ,107.526001 , 162.6710052 ,194.0769958 ,233.6569977, 876.4349976, 418.4100037 ,698.5339966 ,162.121994 , 129.7559967])

# Import the optimization code from scipy.
from scipy import optimize, stats

x=xdata
y=ydata
yerr=d_y
def func(x, m, c):
    return m * x + c
pars, pars_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y, [0, 0])
oneSigmaVariances = np.sqrt(np.diag(pars_covariance))
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = yerr, fmt = '.', label = 'Data')
plt.plot(x, func(x, pars[0], pars[1]), label='Fit')
print('y = ({:.1f} +/- {:.1f}) * x + ({:.1f} +/- {:.1f})'.format(pars[0], oneSigmaVariances[0],pars[1], oneSigmaVariances[1]))
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

Thanks!